# virbr0-nic unmanaged in KVM/Cockpit

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, bridge, cockpit

I am running cockpit on Rocky linux to make a KVM host. I have installed and enabled all 4 nics onboard and they are showing up as managed in the management tab except virbr0-nic

when I run the create VM command I get the following error

```
 ERROR Network not found: no network with matching name 'default' Domain installation 
 does not appear to have been successful. If it was, you can restart your domain by 
 running: virsh --connect qemu:///system start NextCloud otherwise, please restart 
 your installation
```

So I went to the terminal and ran the suggested command as root

```
 virsh --connect qemu:///system start NextCloud
```

I got the following error

```
 error: failed to get domain 'NextCloud'
```

This is the first VM I suspect I have not configured something

Not sure where to go thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After troubleshooting I created a network named 'default' and rebooted it worked.